# Configuring Maximum rows per request in Dataflow Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am using this template:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloudpubsubtobigquery

Reading quota limits under **Maximum rows per request** here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts

They recommend keeping max 500 rows per request.

Where can I configure `Maximum rows per request` in BigQuery sink?
I've searched the whole documentation but did not find any relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for ‘Maximum rows per request’ for inserts in BigQuery is 10,000 rows as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts). The recommended number of rows is 500 per request, but you can experiment by inserting lower or higher number of rows. There is no configuration to limit or modify the number of rows to 500, the only limit is 10,000 rows per request. Quota increases can be requested through the Quotas page in your project and the quota can be increased in increments of 50,000 rows.